# Theia: How to write an extension

Tags: theia

I am trying to write an extension and have the following problem

- If i copy & paste the python extension, change python to python2 and the extension expression for files to py2 and include it in the browser example nothing happens (start never called)
- Same if i simply edit the existing python extension and change the constants like

  `export const PYTHON_LANGUAGE_ID = 'python2';
  export const PYTHON_LANGUAGE_NAME = 'Python2';`

what do i need to do to get my extension running

you can find the code https://github.com/cdietrich/theia/tree/try2 and https://github.com/cdietrich/theia/tree/try1

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with your Python extension. What exactly are you trying to do? Just build any extension for Theia? Or some special functionality?

Comment: problem was solved on theia sides by having more explicit examples that dont rely on default monaco types. if you have different extensions you have to make them known to monaco